# Unwanted color changes of status bar and navigation bar

Tags: android, statusbar, android-theme, android-styles, navigationbar

I'm using the official https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android implementation of EU consent form in my Android game application. I'm facing a prblem with status bar and navigation bar, which lose thir theme/style settings when the form is shown. The problem can be clearly seen on the screnshots below:

[image: nwanted be]

Since it's a fullscreen game, I made the status and navigation bars transparent and black, also hiding by default until user swipes them down/up. But I'm really disturbed as the EU consent form I implemented shows these bars, removes their translucency and shows in wrong colors..

Looking to solve the problem, I need similar behaviour of status and nav bars when the EU Consent Form (GDPR) is shown. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if the consent form is implemented as a non-fullscreen activity, and therefore the status/nav bars are reacting to the new activity's theme

Comment: @BenP. If you know where to look, you can look in the library, I checked it's not big, few classes here and there. However, I wasn't sure where to look, so I asked this question here.

Comment: @BenP. Though I believe that it's a Fragment, not an Activity..